# É possível gerar rotas dinâmicamente no ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou corrigindo algumas URL's do meu site e preciso criar várias rotas diferentes para cada página, por exemplo:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ComoVenderMinhasImagens",
    url: "como-vender-minhas-imagens",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ComoVenderMinhasImagens", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "PerguntasFrequentes",
    url: "perguntas-frequentes",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "PerguntasFrequentes", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "FormasdePagamento",
    url: "formas-de-pagamento",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "FormasdePagamento", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "BancoDeImagens",
    url: "banco-de-imagens",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "BancoDeImagens", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Como no exemplo, preciso criar URL's nas quais as palavras são separadas por `-` em alguns casos, existe alguma ferramente do próprio framework que me permita criar uma rota genérica que funcione para qualquer tipo de Action seja qual for o numero de palavras?

(banco-de-imagens && como-vender-minhas-imagens && perguntas-frequentes && perguntas)

Comment: Você queria uma rota que recebesse na url qualquer conjunto de palavras separado por - e encaminhasse para action que no nome não contem o - 
Exemplo: formas-de-pagamento ser resolvida para FormasDePagamento
Seria isso ?

Comment: Isso, ou o contrário, ele recebesse o nome da Action `FormasDePagamento ` e automaticamente separasse talvez através do upper case e colocasse o `-`

Comment: Porque eu não posso colocar public ActionResult formas-de-pagamento então precisaria colocar FormasDePagamento e a rota automaticamente separasse

Comment: Uma opção seria anotar as actions com o atributo [Route("nome-da-sua-rota")], isso te atende ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no seu controller vc so precisa colocar o `route`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   [Route("")]
   [Route("Home")]
   [Route("Home/Index-EXEMPLO")]
   public IActionResult Index()
   {
      return View();
   }
   [Route("Home/About-EXEMPLO")]
   public IActionResult About()
   {
      return View();
   }
   [Route("Home/Contact-EXEMPLO")]
   public IActionResult Contact()
   {
      return View();
   }
}
```

caso ainda tenha duvida no site da Microsoft explica sobre isso:
[TUTORIAL](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Obrigado Hudson, vou testar a sua resposta e ver se atende... ai marco como ok .Vou ver também se consigo colocar parâmetros dentro desse Route... ai eu edito a resposta para deixar mais completa.

Comment: @LeonardoBonetti parametros vai ficar assim "Home/Contact-EXEMPLO/{var1}/{var2}"